# Subscript and superscript in comments fail

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, formatting, markdown

It would be nice to make subscript and superscript work in comments.

Here, these work :

- `*n*<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>`  →  *n*<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>
- `_n_<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>`  →  *n*<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>

In comments, these fail.

Thank you.

Comment: *n*<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>

Comment: _n_<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>

Comment: These things also work on sites with MathJax enabled, but I've never felt that CodeGolf was mathy enough to make that work asking for.

Comment: Works for me. n₀².

Comment: @xfix — You joker ! Try to write [*u_b^n*](http://jsfiddle.net/b4dDG/) with your trick. [We discuss this trick here in the comments.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1519/12943)

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't work because HTML is not supported in comments. [It has been suggested on Meta Stack Exchange to enable it in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6407/229438), but it got declined. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28523/229438) from [Jeff Atwood ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)

> We do allow very limited markdown in comments now. Click the "help"
>   link below the Add Comment button to get comment formatting help.
>
> - `*` and `_` for bold, italic
> - ``` `` ``` for code blocks
> - `[example](http://example.com "merely an example")`
>
> No HTML, just Markdown in comments, please!

Or, if you really need it, use [Unicode subscript/superscript characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts), as I demonstrated in my comment.

Superscript characters:

```
⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹
```

Subscript characers:

```
₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉
```

Comment: Or use Unicode characters: n₀²

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. But using the ordinary characters is recommended, in particular for accessibility. Moreover, in many cases the workaround is not possible, because only very few characters exist as Unicode subscript or superscript.

Comment: That's true, but unfortunately, there is not really another workaround, apart from putting it in an image, but that's worse for accessibility.

Comment: And an image is not possible in a comment — fortunately.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco: It is possible, you can upload it in the answer field and then post the URL in a comment.

Comment: Upload an image in the answer field? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Italic with * does not always work.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Hmm... that might be because the asterisk is followed by the ² sign, but as far as I can see that's only a problem in comments, not in actual posts.

Comment: Let's test: 4 π *r*². Italic fails!

Comment: Yup, there it does, but it won't fail in questions/answers.